# Does @synchronize protect against race conditions in this case?

Tags: iphone, multithreading, ios, ipad, nsoperationqueue

I want to use Core Data in background threads and NSOperationQueue. Now I thought why shouldn't I just create a class holding all the Core Data stack things with a property of NSManagedObjectContext, and then just make this property atomic?

One thing I'm not sure about `@synchronize(self) {...}` is this: Assume I have a property that's considered thread-safe:

```
@property (retain) NSManagedObjectContext *moc;
```

Every NSOperation or thread accesses an `CoreDataTools` class which has this moc property. They access this moc property like this:

```
// Assume: Inside an NSOperation or new thread here...
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[CoreDataTools sharedInstance] moc];

// Do a lot of things with moc. Add and remove 20 objects.
```

Would this be effective at all? I don't understand WHEN this lock is effective. Just in the event of actually accessing the property? Or can I safely work with the NSManagedObjectContext instance until the NSOperation or called method of the background thread is done and returns?

I know NSMangagedObjectContext has a -lock method. I want to know in general if this would work or not.

Comment: @synchronized(self) { /* lock is effective inside here only */ }

Comment: This was the answer to the question. Make it one and I'll accept it! :=)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 @synchronized(self) { /* lock is effective inside here only */ }
```

Comment: Also, if you really need to lock something, `@synchronized()` is about the slowest way to go: http://perpendiculo.us/?p=133 .

Comment: @Brad Larson - 100 million locks in 10 seconds. I don't think that's all too slow.

Answer (score 2):

No. Each thread should have its own managed object context.

[More info: Concurrency with Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1)

Comment: How about the mechanics of @synchronize in general?

Comment: THe subject is pretty broad to be explained in a whole here but in general @synchronize is recursive lock and can degrade performance if that's what you're after. NSCondition in that regard is much better option.